# Symfony2: mod_rewrite / htaccess to get rid of "web/app.php" ... strange behaviour

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony

I want to get rid of the "web/app.php"+"web/app_dev.php" in the URLs of my symfony2 installation. I know, that virtual host is the best way, but you don't always have you own host. So I tried it with mod_rewrite in the htaccess of my project folder (http://localhost/my-sf2-project/.htaccess) ... how to do it, is explained a lot on here. And fortunately, the rewrite process is doing something with this htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my-sf2-project/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

So that means, when I try to request `http://localhost/my-sf2-project/page/1`, the server should redirect to `http://localhost/my-sf2-project/web/app_dev.php/page/1`. My rewrite log is confirming it:

> internal redirect with /my-sf2-project/web/app_dev.php/page/1
>   [INTERNAL REDIRECT]

But now the strange thing does happen... the symfony2 dev enviroment is saying:

> No route found for "GET /my-sf2-project/page/1"!

That means the request is somehow redirected to

- **http://localhost/my-sf2-project/web/app_dev.php/my-sf2-project/page/1**

instead of

- **http://localhost/my-sf2-project/web/app_dev.php/page/1**

How does that happen? Is there some setting in the apache config or a error in my mod rewrite, that could explain that strange behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want it rewriting to `/my-sf2-project/web/app_dev.php` instead of `/my-sf2-project/web/app_dev.php/page/1` (which doesn't look like should be happening)?

Comment: But why should I want it to rewrite to `/my-sf2-project/web/app_dev.php`? I want to transform the routes too, like in localhost/my-sf2-project **/page/1** ... or maybe I just do not understand the inner workings here. :(